# Is it typical to have a kafka topic per hour or per day?

Tags: apache-kafka, batch-processing

I am logging page visits and search queries (some sort of click stream analysis) to kafka. I intent to batch process them periodically, say per hour or per day, and then write aggregated results to elasticsearch.

If it is not written to kafka, but instead to file system, it is easy to configure the logger to write to a file with time stamp in the file name, which automatically separates logs according to hour/day intervals.

But with kafka, I googled enough times and haven't yet to find any examples of creating a new topic per hour/day. Without creating a new topic per hour/day, I can only imagine moving logs from kafka to file system or hdfs via logstash/flume.

Is it rare to do batch processing (per hour/day) on kafka directly?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you need a new topic per hour/day. Why not send all your logs to a single topic, and do the batch processing? After each processing the committed offset on topic partitions moves ahead, so you won't be reprocessing same logs.

Comment: If all data is written to the same topic, as they might arrive in different orders, which means the `CreatedTime` in the data might not be ordered. It will be difficult to determine the boundaries of each day (although slight inaccuracy might be ok in my case). If there are written to different topics, I can easily check if a particular topic's last modified time is significantly earlier than the current time (assuming my batch runs at 00:10 am every day).

Comment: You could partition the topic logically by a key (in this case, the key could be hour of the day). Kafka will ensure that all messages with the same key go to the same partition and therefore get consumed by a single consumer thread.

Comment: @Rahul that is really a great idea. I can have any number of partitions as long as it is greater than one and then modulo hour by the number of partitions. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka was developed by LinkedIn, and it's role in LinkedIn is log aggregation center. So Kafka is very suitable to deal with this kind of problem.

I think every event (event is like pages visits or queries) should be tagged with a time stamp in your web server not in when the log was sent to Kafka. More specifically, when a page visit event happens, it actually does a request to your web server, and then your web server deal with this request and return the response. Meanwhile, your web server should log this event with a time stamp, and this time stamp is the only right time point for the event. About how to log event? You can create a log_producer to send the log message to the specific topic to your Kafka, not just log this in local file.

And about batch process the log per hour, you could create 24 partitions and make the log "HOUR" as the partition key, then if you do the batch process, you just need pull the partition H's log if the hour you want to process is H .  Because you just need to process the latest H hour's log, the old H'log has been processed and saved by older process work.

Comment: If we make partition for each hour, won't it limit the number of consumers? Since only 1 consumer can read from a partition at a time.